# Scan files and pick overlapped hex codes

Tags: python, regex

## Problem

Two folders having files with name`Efile` that store lines starting with hex codes.

Print those hex codes that overlap in both folders.

---

## Solution

```
import os
import sys
import re

def process_cache(cache):
    event_code_set = set()
    for file_name, multi_line_content in cache.items():
        if file_name.endswith('Efile'):
            for line in multi_line_content.splitlines():
                line = line.rstrip('\\') # trailing backslash, if exist
                if bool(re.search(r'^0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', line)):
                    # Take the hexcode
                    obj = re.search(r'^0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', line)
                    event_code_set.add(obj.string[obj.start():obj.end()])
    return event_code_set



def scan_files(dir):
    cache = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            if name in ('Efile'):
                path = os.path.join(root, name)
                with open(path,'r') as file:
                    cache[path] = file.read()
    return cache

cache1 = scan_files(sys.argv[1])
cache2 = scan_files(sys.argv[2])

cache1_event_code_set = process_cache(cache1)
cache2_event_code_set = process_cache(cache2)

overlap_event_codes = cache1_event_code_set & cache2_event_code_set 
print(overlap_event_codes)
```

---

For a typical three entries in a file, with comments(`#`),

> ```
> 0x00010d35 D 11 G 3,0x10009,N R XY.Condition,   "({a 0x40001} == {H 0x166}) && ({a 0x11ff8} == {I 15})","0x0763ffc2 "
> # Below event codes are from vendor xyz
> 0x84900c5 M 22 Y 1,0x03330469,4,5,6,7,8
> 0x04b60ff6 L 50 U \
>           0x04c60e07,102 && ({a 0x11ff8} == {I 15})","0x0763ffc2 "
> ```

Picking `0x00010d35`, `0x04b60ff6` & `0x84900c5` is the task. Rest of the line is supposed to be ignored

Some entries are multi-line with trailing backslash.

Each file is in megabytes. Total files in both folders - 80

---

1) Please suggest optimization in the below code, because pattern check is done twice.

```
        if bool(re.search(r'^0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', line)):
            # Take the hexcode
            obj = re.search(r'^0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', line)
            event_code_set.add(obj.string[obj.start():obj.end()])
```

2) Please suggest coding style optimizations for tree walk, cache and command line arguments.

Comment: Returning `cache` is a bug and wrong practice, despite it works... `cache1` should not point to local `cache`

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Possible bugs

- In one place, you test for `if file_name.endswith('Efile')`, and elsewhere, you test for `if name in ('Efile')`.  What do you really intend to do?  Are they supposed to be the same test?  Can't you just test the filename once?  The `name in ('Efile')` test is particularly weird, since `'fil'` would pass the test.
- Your regex is case insensitive, which implies that you expect to be able to handle both uppercase and lowercase hex strings.  But your set operations would treat uppercase and lowercase versions of the same hex code as distinct from each other, which is counterintuitive.

  Your sample file shows that the hex codes may have leading zeroes (e.g. `0x00010d35`), and that the codes may have varying lengths.  So, `0x00010d35` would be treated differently from `0x10d35`, which is counterintuitive.

  The solution to both of these issues is to normalize the codes when constructing the set.  One way would be to strip any leading zeroes and convert the string to lowercase.  A better efficient solution would be to parse them as integers, since integer comparisons would be more efficient than string comparisons.
- What's the point of `line = line.rstrip('\\')`?  But what's the point of meddling with the ends of the lines, when you only care about the beginnings of the lines?

  On the other hand, your example file suggests that a backslash at the end of the line would be used to indicate that the following line is a continuation of the same record.  In that case, what if the continuation line starts with something that looks like a hex code (with no leading whitespace)?  Would you count that or not?

### Efficiency

You said that each of the ~100 files may be several megabytes long.  Your `cache` object, reads the entire contents of all of the files into memory!  There is no good reason to store that much data, when all you care about is the hex codes at the beginning of each line.

If you want to split the work into two functions, I would have one of them be responsible for discovering the relevant file paths, and the other one responsible for extracting the codes.

If you run a regex search many times, it's worth compiling it first.  I would design the regex so that it works on the entire file contents at once, rather than line by line.

### Suggested solution

```
import os
import re
import sys

def efiles(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('Efile'):
                yield os.path.join(root, name)

def event_codes(file_paths):
    hex_re = re.compile(r'(?<!\\\n)^0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', re.MULTILINE)
    for path in file_paths:
        with open(path) as f:
            for event_code in hex_re.findall(f.read()):
                yield int(event_code, 16)

event_code_set1 = set(event_codes(efiles(sys.argv[1])))
event_code_set2 = set(event_codes(efiles(sys.argv[2])))
overlap_event_codes = set(hex(n) for n in (event_code_set1 & event_code_set2))
print(overlap_event_codes)
```

Comment: for rstrip? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51409385/3317808

Comment: *continuation line starts with something that looks like a hex code (with no leading whitespace)?* Am not suppose to count... you can say my code is relying on indentation with white space... which is vulnerable... How do I deal with this? Do i need to remember previous line read?

Comment: I actually do not need `endwith` because the file name must be `Efile`.. So `name == 'Efile'` should work

Comment: Yes, I am saying that you are relying on the whitespace. My suggested solution solves it by using a negative look-behind assertion in the regex, and applying the regex to the entire file at once rather than line by line.

Comment: As file is MB size, can I avoid opening of complete file?

Comment: You could write a solution that handles continuation lines while reading only a few lines at a time, but it would be more complicated, and in my opinion, not worth the complication, considering that a couple of MB is no big deal these days. (The same cannot be said for storing the contents of _all_ of the files in memory. That was simply unnecessarily wasteful.)

Comment: For look-behind assertion, do I need to also include zero or more space s?

Answer (score 5):

Repeating the match can be avoided by storing it in a variable first:

```
match = re.search(r'^0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', line)
if match:
    event_codes.add(match.group())
```

Note also that you don't need to strip a trailing `\`, because it is ignored afterwards anyways and you are only interested in hex codes at the beginnings of the line and all your multilines seem to have some whitespace at the beginning of the continued line. Note that you could have used `re.match(r'0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', line)`, instead of `re.search`, because it always matches only the beginning of the line.

Python also caches your regex, once you have used it, but you may still squeeze out a bit of performance with `re.compile`.

I also used the `match.group()` method, which immediately returns the matching part if the string.

---

I would also not suggest caching the file content of all the files in the directories. This seems like a huge waste of memory. Instead process them one at a time and add it to your event code sets, or even better, just generate a stream of event codes that you can consume with `set`:

```
import os
import sys
import re

def event_codes_file(path):
    with open(path) as file:
        for line in file:
            match = re.match(r'0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+', line)
            if match:
                yield match.group()

def event_codes_dir(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('Efile'):
                path = os.path.join(root, name)
                yield from event_codes_file(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_codes1 = set(event_codes_dir(sys.argv[1]))
    event_codes2 = set(event_codes_dir(sys.argv[2]))

    overlap_event_codes = event_codes1 & event_codes2
    print(overlap_event_codes)
```

`yield from x` was [introduced in Python 3.3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) and is mostly equivalent to `for i in x: yield i`.

Also note that `name in ('Efile')` is almost the same as `name == 'Efile'`, but matches a bit more (like `'E'`). Unless of course you meant what you wrote in `process_cache`, `name.endswith('Efile')`. I am assuming the latter.

On a file `"test"`, containing your example content, this produces:

```
set(event_codes_file("test"))
# {'0x00010d35', '0x04b60ff6', '0x84900c5'}
```

Comment: Is  Generator enabling the code to avoid cache?

Comment: @overexchange Basically yes, but it could have been done differently. The important part is processing each file as you discover it, avoiding having to load all of them into memory at once. The generator really only avoids having to carry around a separate `set` per file.

Comment: Yes... Pipe line processing...

Comment: Does `line` not have trailing backslash? Because you are passing to `re.search()`. `re.search(r'\\$', 'hellothere\')` does not work

Comment: @overexchange Yes, I checked that `splitlines` removes it. Also that regex you just showed is irrelevant, because you are basically doing `re.search('hellothere', 'hellothere\')`, which does work.

Comment: So... If I have a merge logic in for-loop then I have to `rstrip('\\')` for sure.. `splitlines()` does not remove it... Please edit your answer...

Comment: @overexchange I'll check again tomorrow when I'm back in front of a PC and edit if necessary.

Comment: `name in ('Efile')` is not the same as `name == 'Efile'`. For example, `'fi' in ('Efile')` is `True`.

Comment: @overexchange: You are right, `splitlines` does not remove it (it would, if the linebreaks were different).

Comment: @overexchange Edited the answer to remove what I was saying about multiline.

Comment: @200_success You are right, did not consider shorter strings. But in conjunction with `endswith` afterwards it is equivalent to it (as you pointed out in your answer as well).

Comment: One should point out that `name in ('Efile',)` *is* the same as `name == 'Efile'` (the comma makes it into a 1-tuple).

Comment: @mkrieger1: While that is true, there is no comma in the OP's code.

Comment: Yes, but maybe using a 1-tuple was what they actually intended to do and didn't know that it wasn't.